# Effective way of page redirecting using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, servlets

I have a login page login.jsp. User validation is done at server side. data is sent using the $http post request. My doubt is on successful login i want to redirect the user to home page. How do i do this..? Do i need to use the RequestDispatcher in servlet or $window.location in Java script. How angular will handle this issues. 
Angular js is used to develop Single Page Applications. Can anyone clearly explain this with an example.

Comment: If it's an SPA [Single page application], You're probably looking for angular routing https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route. If not, Then any of the two approaches will do

Comment: I have tried using the $window.location. The problem here is the login page has a url like `http://localhost:8080/Angular/login.jsp`. 2nd page url needs to be `http://localhost:8080/Angular/home.jsp`. But when i redirect the url is like 'http://localhost:8080/Angular/test.jsp#/Home.jsp`

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `$location` into your controller that handles the login, and use `$location.url('/home')` as seen [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location). It would look something like this:

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', function($location) {
    // whatever code to process login and store user info
    $location.url('/home');
})
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP code, on successful login, use the

```
response.setHeader("Location", site);
```

Useful resource is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_page_redirect.htm

Answer (score 0):

in your angular controller you can use

```
$location.path( "yourpath" );
```

and dont forget to add

```
$scope.apply()
```

after location path